# Search plugin breaking parts of theme

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, themes

I've been asked to add a search function to a website. I'm trying this out on a testing site at http://www.somethingchronic.org.uk (the password to view is Entrand0s1).
I've installed a search plugin which works on all pages except the home page. On that page it clashes with the script in the slider plugin and when I tried deactivating the slider plugin I also lost the four large buttons at the bottom of the page which are part of the theme itself. Both the slider plugin and the theme are old but I'm hoping to keep the site going for a little while longer if I can. I asked for advice from the search plugin developer who said it's to do with the slider loading an older version of the jQuery library. I searched on here for jQuery library conflicts - one answer linked to the learn.jquery website with a list of options for avoiding library conflicts. There were a number of options for adding code - I tried adding some of these to the header.php document but each time the site broke completely and truth is I don't know enough about jQuery to know which is the correct piece of code to try. Any advice appreciated - would be great to know if there is a way to get the search plugin to also work on the home page whilst keeping the current slider. Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to identify where the problem is? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need to give us so that we can help. This site is a repository for questions & answers, so while it is ok to link to your website, questions should be self contained and include all relevant information. This is so that the question can still be useful to others with similar problems even after the issue has been fixed on your website.

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten - many thanks for this guidance on writing a better question. I can see that my one was a bit too general. So far I have asked the Search plugin developer about the problem and they said it's to do with the slider plugin loading an older version of the jQuery library. Unfortunately I don't know enough about jQuery to know if that is fixable. Shall I try editing my original question with this extra info re jQuery library or is it better to delete this question and start again with a fresh one? Many thanks

Comment: You are still asking the same question, so in that case I'd suggest updating this one using the "edit" link under the question and adding in the extra information

Comment: Great, thank you! I've edited the first question to add more info.